# Cannot Format USB Thumb Drives as NTFS

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, ntfs, formatting

I have a bunch of USB thumb drives that I can no longer format as NTFS. But formatting them as FAT32 or exFat works without complications.

I tried formatting them on different computers with Windows 10 1803 and 1809 and Windows Server 2003, I deleted the single partition on the drive and recreated it, but formatting still does not work. I always get the following error message.

> Windows was unable to complete the format.

The diskpart tool shows the drive as not write protected, but I cannot use the clean command, because diskpart could not write to the thumb drives.

I also tried to use the AOMEI Partition Assistant, but the thumb drive does not show up in the list of local drives.

Comment: Are you able to repartition and/or reformat them through Linux (e.g. GParted or mkfs.ntfs or `wipefs --all`)?

Comment: What happens if you delete all partitions before formatting?

Comment: I deleted the single partition on the drive and recreated it, but formatting still does not work.

Comment: @fixer1234: Sorry, but the linked question is a completely other case and the answers do not fit to my problem.

Comment: I tested formatting the sticks with Ubuntu 19.04 and that worked. But I am still curious, what happened to them in the first place.